# Does SpongeWrap (from the Keccak team) absorb ciphertext or plaintext?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, sponge

I have been reading the [Cryptographic sponge functions](http://sponge.noekeon.org/CSF-0.1.pdf) paper, but I'm still confused.

Does Keccak in authenticated encryption mode absorb ciphertext or plaintext?

**Edit:** Are there any test vectors to verify implementation of Keccak authenticated encryption?

Comment: You absorb the plaintext, which means that the rate section of the state is equal to the ciphertext.

Comment: Keccak itself isn't really bothered. It just needs some *input*, now if that happens to be plain or ciphertext depends on the application.

Comment: @figlesquidge Thanks. Are there any test vectors for that?

Comment: @rath I'm asking for "standard" way.

Comment: @trina: http://sponge.noekeon.org/SpongeDuplex.pdf defines the 'SpongeWrap' mode, which is the one referred to in the paper LightBit gives, and I think it's reasonable to say SpongeWrap is the standard construction. That said, expect many more Keccak-based AE modes to come forward in the next few months as [caeser](http://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar.html) submissions come forward.

Comment: @LightBit as far as test vectors go, you could generate them yourself using KeccakTools (https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakTools). Uncomment testKeccakDuplex() in the main function, rebuild, and run. You could also modify testKeccakDuplex() itself to add new test vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The authenticated encryption mode devised by the Keccak team is the SpongeWrap method, and is first described in [this paper](http://sponge.noekeon.org/SpongeDuplex.pdf) — the paper you cite is an amalgamation of all their major sponge papers. The encryption method *wrap* is described in Algorithm 3, on page 10. In particular, lines 14–18 absorb-squeeze with respect to the ciphertext.

In practice it is probably simpler to think of it in the following way:

[image: SpongeWrap diagram]

To implement this in terms of absorbing and squeezing, we have to use the squeezed output from the previous iteration (here called $s_r$, called $z$ in their algorithm) and xor this with the message, before absorbing in the message as part of the next call. In my mind absorbing / squeezing is a much less clear way of describing the process, but mathematically it is important since it clearly shows the object to be an instance of a Duplex Object, which is itself a series of sponges, and thus allows us to use their security proofs.

I do not know of any test vectors for SpongeWrap.

Comment: @Ilmari: Thanks very much for the image! Unfortunately perp doesn't seem to be a constant-width character, rather breaking my ascii art :(