# Are there any online, single pass, AE with associated data auth?

Tags: block-cipher

[AE comparison](https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/docs/AE_comparison_ipics04.pdf) summarizes features of nine AE ciphers and none of them combine features online, one pass, AD auth (see table below). Are out there such ciphers or such combination was proved to be unsecure?

[image: AE comparison table]

Comment: Single-pass vs two-pass is a rather arbitrary distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SpongeWrap](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12221/38781) scheme, which is an AEAD based on the *duplex sponge construction* satisfies all your criterias.

Answer (score 5):

The comparison table is old. OCB has been updated twice since it was first published, supporting associated data since the Asiacrypt 2004 paper. The latest version is OCB3 (but Rogaway suggests it should be called OCB) from a FSE 2011 paper. See http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/ocb-faq.htm#versions

In summary, OCB (versions OCB2 and later) supports AEAD and has supported it since 2004.